# I'm trying to write a highscore to a file in p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using p5js to make a game, and I would like to write the highscore to a text file so that it stays the same when I stop and start the program. Is there a way to edit a text file with code in p5js that already exists?

The only solutions I've seen have involved creating a new file entirely but I want the highscore file to be a part of the project that isn't created when it is run. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your current code attempt. If you haven't made an attempt, I suggest doing so first. What other solutions are you referring to, exactly? That said, instead of using a text file, why not use the browser's [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API? It'll be much simpler--the browser is designed to not be able to write to the user's system without permission.